# Sending variable size 2D array to function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors

I am trying to write  a function which takes variable size array and prints it. But i am having problem in function declaration argument list while compiling.

The error is:

```
cannot convert ‘int (*)[(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)r) + -1)) + 1)]’ to ‘int**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void printHalf(int**, int, int)’
  printHalf( b, r, r);
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printHalf( int **a, int row, int col ) {  // Problem is here.
    for( int i=0; i < row; i++) {
        for( int j=0; j < col; j++) {
            if( i <= j) {
                cout << a[i][j] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int r;
    cout << "No. of rows: ";
    cin >> r;
    int b[r][r];

    for( int i=0; i < r; i++) {
        for( int j=0; j < r; j++) {
            cin >> b[i][j];
        }
    }

    printHalf( b, r, r);
    return 0;
}
```

What is causing this error, and how do i pass various arrays to function?

Comment: @coincoin I think you should use `new[]` instead of `malloc()` in C++.

Comment: I think you should use neither and use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: dont write C code in C++

Comment: Of course my bad I was sure it was a C question ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off `int b[r][r];` is a [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and is not standard in C++.  If you need a container that can be sized at run time then I suggest you use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> data(r, std::vector<int>(r, 0)); // create vector and set all elements to 0
```

Then your print function would become

```
void printHalf(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& data) {
    for( std::size_t i=0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        for( std::size_t j=0; j < data[i].size(); j++) {
            if( i <= j) {
                cout << a[i][j] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using reference to avoid copying many data might be good. `void printHalf(std::vector<std::vector<int>> data)` -> `void printHalf(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& data)`

Comment: I would also recommend to use a flatten/linear `vector<int>` only instead of nested vectors `vector<vector<int>>`.

Comment: @coincoin That is a good suggestion and in production code that is what I would use.  I did not want to present that to the OP as I am already changing to using a vector and wanted to leave the code looking as close the the original as I could.

Answer (score 4):

A 2D array of `[N][M]` is laid out the same in memory as a 1D array of `[N*M]`.

```
void printHalf( int *a, int row, int col ) {  // Problem is here.
    for( int i=0; i < row; i++) {
        for( int j=0; j < col; j++) {
            if( i <= j) {
                cout << a[i*col+j] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it with `printHalf( &b[0][0], r, r)`.

Your fundamental misunderstanding is the relationship between arrays and pointers. Arrays aren't pointers. An `int**` can be viewed as an array of `int*`, which isn't what you have. `b[0]` gets you an `int[r]`. This is different to an `int*`. `b[0][0]` gets you the first `int`.

Comment: You'll want `a[i*col+j]`

Comment: Thank you for giving me C oriented answer, but i guess vector is the way to go for c++

Answer (score 3):

**Problems that I see**

1. C++ does not allow declaration of variable length arrays. Hence,

   ```
   int b[r][r];
   ```

   is wrong.
2. A one dimensional array decays to a pointer but a two dimensional array does not decay to a pointer to pointer. Even if you had `b` defined correctly, such as:

   ```
   int b[10][10];
   ```

   you cannot use `b` as an argument to a function that expects an `int**`.

**Solution**

I suggest use of `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> b(r, std::vector<int>(r));
```

Change the function `printHalf` accordingly.

```
void printHalf( std::vector<std::vector<int>> const& b ) { ... }
```

You don't need `row` and `col` as arguments since that information can be obtained from the `std::vector`.